# Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I used the project on a personal ApplelId. Now I need to change it to the company app.
If I change the AppleId of project in XCode, it gives the following error:
"Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days."
"Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.interNation'."
It works with the same error in the simulator, but does not work on the device.

Comment: You need to make sure you have logged into your company developer account in Xcode preferences and selected the right team in "signing and capabilities".  It sounds like you are still using your personal team

Comment: This is exactly the problem that I have after logging in to the company AplleId. Only the company AplleId is also newly created, no app has been made yet.

Comment: Either they dont have a paid account or you haven't switched the team correctly. Make sure you have also selected "automatic signing"

Comment: Yes they are not connected to the paid tariff yet. Is there a solution to just try using Xcode and use Apple Push Notification via Firebase Messaging?

Comment: You need a paid account to use push notifications

Comment: For test messaging also?

Comment: Yes. Push notifications, even in sandbox mode, need a paid developer agreement.